# Creating a Bitmap/Screenshot from a view

Tags: android, view, bitmap

There is a problem, that prevents some views from getting screenshotted correctly.

Example:
This is how it looks when you added a specific customview, for example a Shape View:
([ShapeOfView](https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView))

[image: View when added]

And this is how it looks if you try to make a screenshot/bitmap from it:
[image: Screenshotted version of the View]

Its easy to see that the custom shape is gone and the drawing is just like in a default view. I found out, that the same problem occurs in some other cases.

> E.g. if you try to make a bitmap from an Emoji added into a TextView,
>   the bitmap will be blank. I thought, that the reason for this lies
>   somewhere between the the device/framework which renders the smileys
>   and the apps code, which is not able to see the Emoji content.

The problem is independend of the code you use to create the screenshot.
Here are some examples I tried:

```
  DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dm.widthPixels,    View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dm.heightPixels, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(),
            v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    v.draw(c);
```

Or:

```
setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); buildDrawingCache(); getDrawingCache();
```

Or even a complete Screenshot:

```
   View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

They all wont work.

Edit:
There are actually libraries that solve the problem correctly, like 
[CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView).
So there has to be a way to also get the ShapeOfView library working.

Answer (score -1):

you can use custom card view with shap Circle

or this library

https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: sorry, but this is not a valid answer. Read again, maybe. Just changing the view wont solve the problem.